# Sort a set and assign the content to a List in java

Tags: java, interface, implements, generics

I have the following java test code that I want to implement:

```
    import java.util.*;

        public class TestRisorseWeb {
          public static void main(String[] args) {

          RisorsaWeb p = new PaginaWeb("index.html","<html><body>main</body></html>"); // name and content
          java.io.File f = new FileWeb("pippo.txt","Questo e' il contenuto\ndi un file di testo.");
        assert f instanceof RisorsaWeb;
        Set<RisorsaWeb> set = new HashSet<RisorsaWeb>();
            set.add(p);
            set.add((RisorsaWeb) f);
            set.add(new PaginaWeb("altraPagina.html","<html><body>altro</body></html>") );

            List<RisorsaWeb> list = Ordina.perCriterioUtente(set, 
                (RisorsaWeb a, RisorsaWeb b) -> a.getNome().compareTo(b.getNome()) ); 
            list.get(0).getNome().equals("altraPagina.html");
            list.get(1).getNome().equals("index.html");
            list.get(2).getNome().equals("pippo.txt");
}
}
```

I don't understand the line:

```
List<RisorsaWeb> list = Ordina.perCriterioUtente(set, 
                    (RisorsaWeb a, RisorsaWeb b) -> a.getNome().compareTo(b.getNome()) );
```

I am trying to figure out what could be **Ordina** ?

A class who has a function called perCriterioUtente ?

Or an object ?

These are the classes and interface I implemented:
PaginaWeb.java

```
  public class PaginaWeb implements RisorsaWeb{

        private String nome, contenuto;     

        public PaginaWeb(String name, String contained) {

            this.nome = name;
            this.contenuto = contained;
        }


    }
```

RisorsaWeb.java

```
public interface RisorsaWeb {

    }
```

and FileWeb.java:

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileWeb extends File implements RisorsaWeb  {

    private String nome, contenuto;

    public FileWeb(String name, String contained){

        super(name);
        this.contenuto = contained;
    }


}
```

Comment: isn't the test code yours? If you don't know what's Ordina, with the given information how are we to find out what it is?

Comment: If the code follows java Naming conventions, Ordina should be a class rather than an object, so the method should be static. There is, however, no guarantee of this with the code you've given us.

Comment: Okay.. so you have the test code and you're trying to write the program that satisfies the test? If so, it looks like a class with a static method `perCriterioUtente `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be you are looking for:
I think this will create a list and sort it.

```
public class Ordina{
    public static List<RisorsaWeb> perCriterioUtente(Set<RisorsaWeb> unstorted, Comparator<RisorsaWeb> comparator){
        List<RisorsaWeb> list = new ArrayList<RisorsaWeb>();
        list.addAll(unsorted);
        Collections.sort(list,comparator);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Note: writed only with javadoc so not tested.